# ReSharper 9.1 Live Templates editor doesn't allow to change any options

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, live-templates, resharper-9.1

I use ReSharper 9.1 with Visual Studio 2013 and I have an issue with Live Templates editor. Non of checkbox options are editable. If I click on any of them - they are not changed.

I've tried to clear ReSharper cache and reinstall it, but the issue still remains. I have it both with existing templates and if I try to create a new one.

Comment: I have a similar issue, and my Fonts and Colors setting is missing. I've done an in-place re-install to no avail.

Comment: I am using Resharper 9.1 as well but don't have this issue, maybe you should report a bug to resharper.